# Build constraints exclude all the Go files

Tags: go

I'm newbie to go and I've created a file and init a mod inside of it by typing:

`go mod init github.com/AnmarDc/e-commerce`

After that, I made a folder called controllers which will contain all the controllers of my operations on my site and then tried to import it into my routes folder, but that didn't work.
I kept getting the following error:

`Build constraints exclude all the Go files in 'C:/Users/engan/Go/src/Projects/eCommerce/controllers'`

*I thought it was about GoPath, or GoRoot, but I found it out it's because GoLand itself, but I have no idea how to fix it, as I can see everything seems reasonable to me.*

GoEnv attached.

[image: Env]

[image: Structure of the project:]

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it looks like there's some issue in building constraints, I just imported the following code in my routers:

```
//go:build (linux && 386) || (darwin && !cgo)
```

and it worked perfectly.

Reference:
[Constraints](https://kofo.dev/build-tags-in-golang)